# Как откинуть значение через : если есть число и строка?

Tags: python, массивы, print, split

Имеем значение в переменной `spb_fc5: 5861.1999999999998`

Как мне распечатать только `5861.1999999999998`?

> split AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split' на это ругается.

Comment: а как вы пытались распечатать?

Comment: @S.Nick  r = s.split(':') , print(r)

Comment: а что такое `s`?

Comment: @S.Nick s = ("spb_fc5: 5861.1999999999998")

Comment: `print(s.split(': ')[-1])`

Comment: @S.Nick AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'split' теперь такая ошибка

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример, который вы запускаете ! я не понимаю как вы добиваетесь получать такие ошибки: ... 'dict'...,  ...'long'...

Comment: @S.Nick  response_emc_space = requests.request("GET", url_emc_space, headers=headers, data=load_emc, verify=False)

    res_emc_space = json.loads(response_emc_space.text)
    emc_space_total = res_emc_space['content']['tiers'][2]['sizeTotal']
    print(emc_space_total.split(': ')[-1])

Comment: покажите результат `print(emc_space_total)`

Comment: у вас словарь? Вы сначала сказали что имеете переменную. mydict.get('spb_fc5')

Comment: @S.Nick {u'spb_fc5': u'1756.4000000000001'}

Comment: `print(*[ v for v in emc_space_total.values() ])`

Answer (score 1):

Это просто. Используйте метод `split`.

```
s = "spb_fc5: 5861.1999999999998" 
print(s.split(": ")[-1])
# 5861.1999999999998
```